# Fix images in bootstrap rails

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I am creating a rails application using bootstrap.  In my header, I am creating a carousel that provides links to other pages.  My images are of different sizes and the carousel keeps reflecting this.  I do not want the carousel to change size based on the images.  How can I fix this so all of the images are the same size within the carousel?

Thanks for any help given in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I guess the easiest option would be to resize them all to the same size using well any photo editor or even online.

Google output:

http://www.picresize.com/

Alternatively you could use a gem like carrierwave or paperclip. More complex but if you are going to have images like profile pictures then it might be useful.

Bye